# How to test if a named pipe exists?

Tags: bash

In order to test if a file exists I do:

```
if [ -f $FILE ];
```

but it doesn't work if $FILE is a named pipe, 
e.g. `ls -l pipename` shows a pipe with **p** attribute:

```
prw-r--r-- 1 usr grp 0 Nov 26 02:22 pipename
```

How to test if a named pipe exists?

Comment: Here is all bash test expressions. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Answer (score 26):

You could use the `-p` test

```
if [[ -p $pipe ]]
```

or

```
if [ -p "$pipe" ]
```

Answer (score 7):

The friendly man page lists several file test operators, including:

```
-e file
       True if file exists.
```

and

```
-f file
       True if file exists and is a regular file.
```

and

```
-p file
       True if file exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).
```

Don't just use `-f` all the time; use the one that does the thing you mean.

Comment: `test`'s manpage, I guess ? (I used to look them up in e.g. bash manpage, but that's far from being efficient)

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
if [[  -p $pipe ]]
```

or you can simply try by removing the `[]` like this:

```
if [ -p "$pipe" ]
```

Also check [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) and [Bash Shell: Check File Exists or Not](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-existence-of-file-in-bash/)